# Why am I getting warning that a non-nullable field must be initialised (When I'm sure I'm initialising it)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have:

```
public abstract class Craft
{
    public Craft()
    {
        CurrentQuadrant = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    private Point _currentQuadrant;
    public Point CurrentQuadrant
    {
        get => _currentQuadrant;
        set
        {
            _currentQuadrant = value;
        }
    }
}
```

(Point is a simple x-y pair).

Why would that be giving me the warning that `Non-nullable field '_currentQuadrant' must contain a non-null value when exiting the constructor`? Doesn't the assignment make sure it's non-null?

Comment: I don't think the linked answer actually helps you. The problem is that the compiler isn't smart enough to see that you assign the `CurrentQuadrant` property, and that in turn always assigns the `_currentQuadrant` field. Either set `_currentQuadrant` directly from the constructor, or make `CurrentQuadrant` an auto-property without an explicit backing field, i.e. `public Point CurrentQuadrant { get; set; }`

Comment: `_currentQuadrant = new Point(0, 0);`

Comment: @Wyck Nullable Reference Types came out with C# 8, 2 major versions ago

Comment: *I'm sure I'm..* - if you've reached a point where youre certain youre being more clever than the compiler is capable of giving you credit for, warning suppression applies

Comment: The compiler is warning that we should assign `_currentQuadrant` a value before exiting the constructor.  It appears that we did, albeit indirectly, by calling the property setter for `CurrentQuadrant`.  Is there maybe some way an exception could occur that would leave `_currentQuadrant` without a value?  This question needs an answer that is not provided in the duplicate.  e.g.: like canton7's first comment, which hints that the actual reason is that the compiler isn't smart enough (yet)  to conclude that an assignment happened in this case.

Comment: As Caius said (`_currentQuadrant = new Point(0, 0);`), plus if you do that you can remove the default constructor entirely.

Comment: Thanks, all. I needed reassuring that I hadn't missed a way it could end up null. Oh, and there's a reason I need it backed by a member and can't use a default constructor, but I'd simplified it away to create a minimum example for my question.

Comment: One very good reason to leave the constructor as-is (and suppress the warning) is if one wants to add some validation logic for the `Point` that should be shared between the constructor and the setter. Of course, there are other ways around the problem, but the straightforwardness of handing validation in the setter is compelling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Too little reputation to comment, so I'll post it here.

If you're using .NET 5+, you can use the `[MemberNotNull]` attribute (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullattribute?view=net-6.0)).

Just put `[MemberNotNull(nameof(_currentQuadrant)]` on your constructor and the warning will disappear.

Or you could just assign the value to `_currentQuadrant` instead of `CurrentQuadrant`.

Comment: I put the `[MemberNotNull(nameof(_currentQuadrant)]` attribute at the top of the `CurrentQuadrant` setter instead of the constructor and that did the trick.